# SQL Order by where dates not equal

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Have the table:

```
Game
----------
ID
UploadDate
LastUpdate
```

Where `UploadDate` is the date the game was uploaded, and `LastUpdate` is the date of the last update for the game.

New games will have `UploadDate == LastUpdate`.

I want to return `Most recently updated games`.  They should be ordered by `LastUpdate` descending, but if `UploadDate == LastUpdate` they should be pushed to the bottom of the list.

I've tried:

```
ORDER BY UploadDate <> LastUpdate, LastUpdate DESC
```

But the syntax is incorrect.  Can anyone help me with this order by query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax you are using is appropriate for MySQL.  The following works in almost all databases:

```
ORDER BY (case when UploadDate <> LastUpdate then 1 else 0 end) desc, LastUpdate DESC
```

Comment: Beat me by 11 seconds

Answer (score 2):

You're very close - the order by clause needs values to order by - not boolean conditions. Instead, you can wrap the condition in a CASE statement, for example:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN UploadDate <> LastUpdate THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, LastUpdate DESC
```

Comment: No, I think that pushes `UploadDate <> LastUpdate` to the bottom of the list, when they want `UploadDate == LastUpdate` at the bottom of the list.

Comment: `1` and `0` should be other way around... or `DESC` instead of `ASC`.. or `=` instead of `<>` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN UploadDate = LastUpdate THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ASC, LastUpdate DESC
```